# How do I use a different condition if there are empty results on the condition of a $match of a $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, null, aggregation-framework

Using the `mongoDb Aggregation framework`; suppose I wanted to [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) a set of results in another collection with a condition that if returned no results - would then return the results of another condition. This is what I have.

**srp collection**

```
   [
      {
         "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db87"),
         "dates_e": {
            "from": ISODate("2021-10-01"),
            "to": ISODate("2021-10-03")
         }
      },
      {
         "_id": ObjectId("5f034bfa4c0000abdfc7df2e"),
         "dates_e": {
            "from": ISODate("2021-03-10"),
            "to": ISODate("2021-03-15")
         }
      },
      ..
   ]
```

**uth collection**

```
   [
      {
         "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db88"),
         "dateTime": ISODate("2021-10-01"),
         "res": 1.7
      },
      {
         "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db89"),
         "dateTime": ISODate("2021-10-02"),
         "res": 0.5
      },
      ..
   ]
```

The aggregation query (on the `srp collection`):

```
   [
      {
         $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db87") }
      },
      {
         $lookup: {
            "from": "uth",
            "let": {
               "fromDate": "$dates_e.from",
               "toDate": "$dates_e.to"
            },
            "pipeline": [
               $match: {
                  $expr: {
                     $and: [
                        {
                           $gte: ["$varData_e.dateTime", "$$fromDate"]
                        },
                        {
                           $lt: ["$varData_e.dateTime", "$$toDate"]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ],
            "as": "uth_e"
         }
      }
   ]
```

Which would return:

```
   [
      {
         "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db87"),
         "dates_e": {
            "from": ISODate("2021-10-01"),
            "to": ISODate("2021-10-03")
         },
         "uth_e": [
            {
               "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db88"),
               "dateTime": ISODate("2021-10-01"),
               "res": 1.7
            },
            {
               "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db89"),
               "dateTime": ISODate("2021-10-02"),
               "res": 0.5
            },
            {
               "_id": ObjectId("5fb6727790f41fef3ee7db90"),
               "dateTime": ISODate("2021-10-03"),
               "res": 2.8
            }
        ]
   ]
```

So this works just fine. However if the `$match` was `"_id": ObjectId("5f034bfa4c0000abdfc7df2e")` and there weren't any results returned (on the `$lookup` from `uth`) then I would like to return a set of results for a broader condition:

```
   [
      {
         $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5f034bfa4c0000abdfc7df2e") }
      },
      {
         $lookup: {
            "from": "uth",
            "let": {
               "fromDate": "$dates_e.from",
               "toDate": "$dates_e.to"
            },
            "pipeline": [
               $match: {
                  $expr: {
                     $gte: ["$varData_e.dateTime", "$$fromDate"]
                  }
               }
            ],
            "as": "uth_e"
         }
      }
   ]
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Return alternative value in a separate property. Add the logic which field to include in the result on the next $project stage

Comment: @Alex Blex - thanks for the response. I'm not looking to return a static value - I'm wanting to change the condition of the `$lookup`. I've edited the question for less confusion.